# Google Directory API Access using Java

Tags: java, google-api-java-client, google-admin-sdk

I am trying to fetch and update the Users of my domain using Google Admin API

```
  private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
  private static final List<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList(
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly");

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();


      GoogleCredential credential =
          new GoogleCredential.Builder()
              .setTransport(httpTransport)
              .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
              .setServiceAccountId(
                  "xxxxx-yyyyy@developer.gserviceaccount.com")
              .setServiceAccountUser("sysadmin@mydomain.com")
              .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES)
              .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(
                  new File("C:\\privatekey.p12")).build();

      Directory admin =
          new Directory.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
              .setApplicationName("User Sync Service")
              .setHttpRequestInitializer(credential).build();

      Directory.Users.List list = admin.users().list();
      list.setDomain("mydomain.com");
      Users users = list.execute();
      System.out.println("************");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

I am getting this error

```
com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "error" : "access_denied"
}
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException.from(TokenResponseException.java:105)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:287)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.execute(TokenRequest.java:307)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.executeRefreshToken(GoogleCredential.java:269)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:489)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.intercept(Credential.java:217)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:858)
```

**Screenshots:**
[image]
[image]

Comment: If there's any way to directly access API using username and password or some other way, please post it. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specific error you are seeing probably means that you did not give the service account access to the Google Apps domain in the CPanel's 3rd party OAuth settings. This step is described in the [Google Drive domain-wide delegation documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation#delegate_domain-wide_authority_to_your_service_account) (just sub in the Directory scopes).

Also, rather than using a service account, you may just want to use a regular OAuth 2.0 token for [web servers](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer) or [installed applications](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp). It's still not as simple as just supplying an admin user/pass but it's simpler than service accounts and it's much more secure than user/pass access since you're scoping the access and not touching the user password directly.

Comment: This solved the problem. Was banging my head for almost 1 week. The Google Documentation is quite misleading. Better it should be updated properly

Comment: one small help. How to log request and response in Console. is there any way to log them?

Comment: But if you use regular oauth tokens instead of a service account, you'll have to manually authorize your application when it starts, which is not comfortable, specially if you are running a Spring Boot application on Docker, which is my case.

Comment: Nico, get and store a refresh token the first time. Then you can get an access token whenever your app runs. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#httprest_1